# String replace certain matching group, not the whole match

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

In js I want to replace newlines in a string with some text but only when the \n is preceded by a dot and optionally whitespace(s). Sample text:

> First sentence comes
>   split in two lines.
>
> This would be a new sentence.
>
> And the end

Should become

```
"First sentence comes split in two lines.<br>This would be a new sentence.<br>And the end"
```

Using a regexp:

```
text = text.replace(/\.\s(*\n)/g, "<br>");
```

replaces the whole match, thus eating the dot and, to my knowledge, RegEx.repace does not provide a way to replace only the matching group.

What would be the simplest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture a literal dot in a group, then a newline followed by 0+ whitespace chars.

In the replacement use group 1 followed by a break:  `$1<br>`

```
\s*(\.)?\n\s*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BGUbSY/1/)

```js
const regex = /\s*(\.)?\n\s*/gm;
const str = `First sentence comes   
split in two lines.

This would be a new sentence.

And the end`;
const subst = `$1<br>`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

If you want to remove the first `<br>` as well, you might also opt to do it in 2 steps:

```js
const str = `First sentence comes   
split in two lines.

This would be a new sentence.

And the end`;
const result = str.replace(/\s*(\.)\s*/g, "$1<br>").replace(/\s*\n+\s*/g, " ");
console.log(result);
```